# Dask KubeCluster not using kubectl config

Tags: kubernetes, dask, dask-kubernetes

I'm attempting to run a dask hello world program on a Kubernetess cluster to which I have (limited) access. I'm running this in Windows 10. Using kubectl in powershell, I can successfully create a pod from a yaml file that pulls and runs a docker container. This works because I've also previously set up my config in ~/.kube/config to specify the namespace and my authorization.

To do the same programmatically (I hope):

```py
import os
from dask_kubernetes import KubeCluster, KubeConfig
from dask.distributed import Client
import dask.array as da

path_to_src = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
cluster = KubeCluster(os.path.join(path_to_src, 'pod-spec.yaml'))
client = Client(cluster)

# Create a large array and calculate the mean
array = da.ones((1000, 1000, 1000))
print(array.mean().compute())  # Should print 1.0
```

But this leads to a permissions error:

```
HTTP response body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"pods is forbidden: User \"<not_my_kubectl_config_username>\" cannot create resource \"pods\" in API group \"\" in the namespace \"default\"","reason":"Forbidden","details":{"kind":"pods"},"code":403}
```

The error suggests that it is not using my kubectl config because the user name is not the one I use for kubectl, and the namespace should not be default. The documentation suggests that KubeCluster will use the kubectl config file if it's in the default location (~/.kube/config), so I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: how do you start your programm? is it spawned by your user, oder someone elses? also what is the value of $KUBECONFIG and $HOME on your system.

Comment: It is spawned by my Windows user (not my user which has k8s access).
$HOME is set to "C:\Users\<my id>"
$KUBECONFIG appears unset.

Comment: from the documentation about dask-kubernetes kubeconfig: https://kubernetes.dask.org/en/latest/kubecluster.html#dask_kubernetes.KubeConfig

I think it tries to load kubeconfig form ~/home/.kube/config as default as your $KUBECONFIG is not set. i am not sure if the default sring as defined maps well to windows. can you try exporting KUBECONFIG on your system or specify the path to the kubeconfig in your application?

Comment: Exactly - I was counting on the default location to work (I understand your suggestion though). I set KUBECONFIG as well just now, but the error (and displayed username) are unchanged. I tried setting the path a few different ways to be sure (Linux/Windows, escaped/not escaped) but nothing changed with any approach.

Comment: The username is actually correct - I think I'm confusing my username with the role binding because of how it appears in the kube config file. I've been given access to a different K8s environment with a more "intentional" role and am not having this problem, so I'm going to blame the original error on permissions - not a missing config necessarily.